# how to convert a string to an array in php

Tags: php

how to convert a string in array in php i.e

```
$str="this is string";
```

should be like this

```
  arr[0]=this
  arr[1]=is
  arr[2]=string
```

The `str_split($str, 3);` splits the string in 3 character word but I need to convert the string after whitespace in an array.

Comment: It helps to [read the manual](http://php.net/str_split), especially to follow the related functions linked at the end of each article...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

```
$array = explode(' ', $string);
```

The first argument is delimiter

Comment: if the string doesn't need to be exploded, you can cast it this way 
`$array = [$string];`

Answer (score 9):

With [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function of php

```
$array=explode(" ",$str);
```

This is a quick example for you http://codepad.org/Pbg4n76i

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php

$str = "Hello Friend";

$arr1 = str_split($str);
$arr2 = str_split($str, 3);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);

?>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 5):

try json_decode like so

```
<?php

   $var = '["SupplierInvoiceReconciliation"]';
   $var = json_decode($var, TRUE);
   print_r($var);
?>
```

Comment: The OP's input data is not json.

Comment: Also -- The return (In PHP 8) is `Array ( [0] => SupplierInvoiceReconciliation )`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in PHP specifically designed for that purpose, [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php). By default it does not take into account the numbers and multibyte characters, but they can be added as a list of additional characters in the `charlist` parameter. Charlist parameter also accepts a range of characters as in the example.

One benefit of this function over `explode()` is that the punctuation marks, spaces and new lines are avoided.

```
$str = "1st example:
        Alte Füchse gehen schwer in die Falle.    ";

print_r( str_word_count( $str, 1, '1..9ü' ) );

/* output:
Array
(
    [0] => 1st
    [1] => example
    [2] => Alte
    [3] => Füchse
    [4] => gehen
    [5] => schwer
    [6] => in
    [7] => die
    [8] => Falle
)
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

explode() might be the function you are looking for

```
$array = explode(' ',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

**explode** — Split a string by a string

Syntax :

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
```

- $delimiter :  based on which you want to split string
- $string.  : The string you want to split

Example :

```
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

In your example :

```
$str = "this is string"; 
$array = explode(' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this even without using explode and implode function.
Here is the example:

**Input**:

> This is my world

**Code**:

```
$part1 = "This is my world"; 
$part2 = str_word_count($part1, 1);
```

**Output**:

> Array( [0] => 'This', [1] => 'is', [2] => 'my', [3] => 'world');

Comment: This is just a repeat of @Danijel's answer from years earlier.

Answer (score 0):

here, Use explode() function to convert string into array, by a string

[click here to know more about explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "this is string";
$delimiter = ' ';  // use any string / character by which, need to split string into Array
$resultArr = explode($delimiter, $str);  
var_dump($resultArr);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => "this",
    [1] => "is",
    [2] => "string "
)
```

it is same as the requirements:

```
  arr[0]="this";
  arr[1]="is";
  arr[2]="string";
```

Comment: This very late answer adds no value to this page.  If you wanted to offer a link to the php manual, you could have edited the accepted answer or left a comment under the question.